# Trying to querySelectorAll on OLX page, but seems like Puppeteer is not allowed

Tags: puppeteer

I try to `querySelectorAll`, but when Puppeteer is doing that he gets nothing. Is there a way to see if they have some bot-preventing measures in place?

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    // headless: 'new',
    headless: false,
    slowMo: true,
    args: ['--start-maximized'] 
  })

  const page = await browser.newPage()
  
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});

  const url = 'https://www.olx.pl/moda/akcesoria/'

  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})

  const cookies = await page.waitForSelector('#onetrust-accept-btn-handler', {
    timeout: 5000
  })

  cookies.click()
  
  await page.waitForSelector('.css-oukcj3')

  const grid = await page.evaluate(
    () => document.querySelector('.css-oukcj3')
  )

  console.log(grid)

  const elements = await page.evaluate(
    () => document.querySelectorAll('.css-1sw7q4x')
  )

  console.log('elements: ', elements)

  await browser.close()
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of selecting `.css-oukcj3`, select the elements that repeat `.css-1sw7q4x` or `[data-cy=l-card]` then loop through them to get the information you want.

Code :

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--no-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    let url = 'https://www.olx.pl/moda/akcesoria/';

    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 0 });
    const cookies = await page.waitForSelector('#onetrust-accept-btn-handler', {timeout: 5000});
    cookies.click();
    await page.waitForSelector('.css-oukcj3');

    // relevant part
    let items = await page.$$('[data-cy=l-card]');
    let list = [];
    for (let p of items) {
        let link = await p.$eval('a', el => el.getAttribute("href")); 
        let name = await p.$eval('h6', el => el.innerText);
        let price = await p.$eval('[data-testid=ad-price]', el => el.innerText); 
        list.push({link: link, name: name, price: price});
    }
    // relevant part end 

    console.log(list);

    await page.close();
    await browser.close();

})().catch(err => console.error(err)). finally(() => browser ?. close());
```